# convert from ascii (dos) to windows

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Hi I have  a string written in ascii code whose output  is **"    ”˜‰ƒ ‰™˜€"** this is a name in Hebrew. How can I convert it to Hebrew letters? 
.net c# winform

Comment: Smart programmers can be pretty religious about characters and strings. You need to distinguish between the visual display of characters and string and their internal representation.

Comment: Where is this string? What encoding does it use?

Answer (score 3):

There are no Hebrew letters in ASCII, so you have to mean ANSI. There is a default encoding for the system that is used for encoding ANSI, which you need to know to decode it.

It's probably the Windows-1255 or ISO 8859-8 encoding that was used. You can use the `Encoding` class to decode the data. Example:

```
Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO 8859-8").GetString(data);
```

If you already have a string, the problem is that you have decoded data using the wrong encoding. You have to go further back in the process before the data was a string, so that you can get the actual encoded bytes.

If you for example are reading the string from a file, you have to either read the file as bytes instead, or set the encoding that the stream reader uses to decode the file data into characters.